# С помощью регулярного выражения заменить одиночный символ (при этом не трогать те же символы, стоящие в группе)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста составить регулярное выражение. Ходя бы подскажите в какую сторону смотреть.

Собственно суть: Требуется заменить (с помощью `preg_replace()`) на одиночный символ (например "@"), но при этом не трогать этот символ стоящий в группе (например "@@").

Иначе говоря:

Имеется строка:

```
$string = "@any text @@@ more @ text@@ @ and@ more @text@@@@"
```

В ней требуется заменить **"@"** на **"#"**, и на выходе получить:

```
"#any text @@@ more # text@@ # and# more #text@@@@"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
$string = "@any text @@@ more @ text@@ @ and@ more @text@@@@";
echo preg_replace('/(^|[^@])@([^@]|$)/', '$1#$2', $string);
```

Проверяем, что предыдущий и последующий символы не @ и заменяем.

---

Такое решение не вполне корректно, так как не работает в случае дистанции между нужными символами в один символ: `"@ @test" -> "# @test"`

Поэтому нужно применять `lookahead`:

```
$string = "@any text @@@ more @ text@@ @ and@ more @ @text@@@@";
echo preg_replace('/(^|[^@])@(?!@)/', '$1#', $string);
```

Comment: Такого в исходной строке не ожидается вроде, но спасибо большое, на будущее буду знать!

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php) и регуляркой с [просмотром](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E5%E3%F3%EB%FF%F0%ED%FB%E5_%E2%FB%F0%E0%E6%E5%ED%E8%FF#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%91%D0%B4_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4) вперед и назад

```
/(?<!@)@(?!@)/
```

Тест регулярки https://regex101.com/r/lDMrkh/1